# Remove 3rd row with day of week from Windows 10 taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, date

After a recent update my Windows added a 3rd row to the taskbar, showing the full day of week. I don't need it since I have one as part of the date.

Moreover, the 3rd row made my date disappear as well.

How do I get rid of it?

[image: Huge taskbar shows redyndant day of week]

[image: Usual taskbar shows no date]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taskbar/system tray suddenly changed to 3 rows. How do I get my one row taskbar back in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/1265087/taskbar-system-tray-suddenly-changed-to-3-rows-how-do-i-get-my-one-row-taskbar)

Comment: Your own picture has a potential solution. In the "Date Formats" section, 'ddd' and 'dddd' are placeholders for 'day of the week'. Try removing those, or changing them for 'd' or 'dd'

Answer (score 4):

**To get a 2-line date/time field:**

Right-click on the taskbar and make sure "Lock the taskbar" is not checked.

Resize the taskbar to a single line of icons (smaller).

**To get a 1-line date/time field:**

Right-click on the taskbar and click "Takbar settings".

Set "Use small taskbar buttons" to "On".

When the taskbar is a double-row of icons it allows for 3 rows of data in the date/time field. Setting this to a single row of icons allows for a 2 row date/time field. Setting the icons to small sets the date/time field to a single row.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the Day of the Week from the date section of the taskbar, simply right-click on the taskbar and go to Taskbar Settings. Turn off Use Small Taskbar Buttons. Right-click again on the taskbar and untick Lock the Taskbar on the menu. Go back to the taskbar and adjust the width to hide the Day of the Week. You may Lock the Taskbar again to keep the desired settings.

Comment: "The width" of what? There's the taskbar itself, then sliders for the individual toolbars *within* the taskbar. No amount of adjusting the taskbar size removes the day of the week for me, regardless of the "Use small taskbar buttons" setting.

Comment: The solution was to remove any active Toolbars (i.e., "Desktop") with [Right-click the taskbar] > Toolbars and unticking them. Then you can re-add them without affecting the taskbar's size. Definitely a bug. This third-row issue arose for me after moving the taskbar to the left/right of the screen, then back to the bottom.